# Htaccess redirect url with raw php url containing variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using a CMS that rewrites all URLs and currently I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/folder/?user=user1
```

I'm looking to have that rewrite to:   `index.php?r=search&term=$1`

Would something like this work?

```
RewriteRule ^/?user=(.*) index.php?r=search&term=$1 [L]
```

Seems to be giving me trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://perishablepress.com/stupid-htaccess-tricks/  this may helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is not part of the URI-path test it in the rule. It is at QUERY_STRING variable.

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/?  /index.php?r=search&term=%1  [L,NC]
```

Comment: What is this `[^/]`? Do you mean `[^&]`?

Comment: @Olaf Good question. I had my doubts about that too, but assume the query string is just as described and eventually could end with a slash, like `http://www.domain.com/folder/?user=user1/`. That might happen if it is manually entered. Could have used `&` in case there are more key-value pairs, as you say. Doesn't seem there are, though.

Answer (score 0):

try ( not tested)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^folder1/?user=(.*)$ index.php?r=search&term=$1 [R=301,L]
```